Trouble launching gsconnect on Debian 12 Cinnamon
This is the Error I get when I try to open my gnome extensions app:


Apparently, KDE Connect works on Cinnamon so if anyone else has this issue I recommend using KDE Connect instead if someone has another solution though that would be greatly appreciated.
